# How to run node js application programmatically using forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I need to run the set of node js files which contains the configuration information where It has to run typically port number and IP address then using the forever in node.js I need to run the script in the terminal with the configuration without having any manual input.

Answer (score 3):

For Programmatic approach , you can use [Forever-Moniter](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor)

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

  var child = new (forever.Monitor)('your-filename.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
  });

  child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('your-filename.js has exited after 3 restarts');
  });

  child.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the child_process module. Check the doc, there're some useful information there: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

**To give a brief example**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('forever', function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
    // cb
});
```

If you don't need a callback / don't want to wait for the execution:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec('forever').unref();
```

Was that helpful?

Best
Marc

Edit: Ok, not sure if I really got the point of your question, but my answer combined with https://stackoverflow.com/a/23871739/823851 might offer a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

- forever start hello.js to start a process.
- forever list to see list of all processes started by forever
- forever stop hello.js to stop the process, or forever stop 0 to stop the process with index 0 (as shown by forever list).

Answer (score -2):

[node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) is a good module for managing different configurations of a Node.js app.

For example, to make a "production" config, `/config/production.json` would contain:

```
{
  "port" : "3000",
  "ip" : "192.168.1.1"
}
```

In one of your node application JS files:

```
config = require('config')
....
var port = config.port;
var ip = config.ip;
```

And to launch the app in this configuration, just first set your NODE_ENV to production from the shell before running your app.

```
export NODE_ENV=production
forever start app.js
```

Make additional config JSON files as needed for each of your environments. `default.json` is used when no environment is specified.

Comment: This is not a programmatically approach .

Comment: node-config is a great module, but it doesn't answer the question here.